# IntegrityError with DateField - when creating objects with get_or_create

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, datefield

I'm having an issue with Django's get_or_create, when ever I create same objects with same dates integrity error pops up.

I have field in my model as follows.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        pgettext_lazy('Cart field', 'created'), auto_now_add=True)
    last_status_change = models.DateTimeField(
        pgettext_lazy('Cart field', 'last status change'), auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='carts',
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('Cart field', 'user'))
    email = models.EmailField(
        pgettext_lazy('Cart field', 'email'), blank=True, null=True)

    def add(self,hoarding, date_from, date_until):
        cart_line, created = self.lines.get_or_create(
            hoarding=hoarding,date_from=date_from,date_until=date_until)



class Meta:
        ordering = ('-last_status_change',)
        verbose_name = pgettext_lazy('Cart model', 'Cart')
        verbose_name_plural = pgettext_lazy('Cart model', 'Carts')

    def __str__(self):
        return smart_str(self.user)


class CartLine(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        Cart, related_name='lines',
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('Cart line field', 'cart'))

    hoarding = models.ForeignKey(
        Hoarding, related_name='+',blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('Cart line field', 'hoarding'))

    date_from = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('Cart line field', 'from'))

    date_until = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('Cart line field', 'until'))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('cart', 'date_from', 'date_until')
        verbose_name = pgettext_lazy('Cart line model', 'Cart line')
        verbose_name_plural = pgettext_lazy('Cart line model', 'Cart lines')
```

error arises when i try to add same objects to cart with same from-date and until-date:

```
IntegrityError at /hoardings/hoardings-demo-2-5/add/
UNIQUE constraint failed: cart_cartline.cart_id, cart_cartline.date_from, cart_cartline.date_until
```

`get_or_create` will return an IntegrityError when creating objects with same dates.I added unique features in datefield but got the same error. I use Django 1.11 and Python 2.7

I reset database few times but it doesn`t help, db is Postgres/sqlite.

Comment: Have you written any thing in `Meta` class of the model?

Comment: There's no unicity constraint in the models code you posted. Either you didn't post the full code or the unicity contraint has been declared at the db level or whatever, but since we cannot reproduce the error with only this code we cannot help.

Comment: @zaidfazil class `Meta` added  ,please see ?

Comment: @user3334294 Now that you added the `Meta` class, it's the `unique_together` in the `CartLine` model that is causing this. Just remove that line and migrate (or recreate the DB again, since you seem to be in a phase that allows that).

Comment: @user3334294 its worked ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unique_together` constraint is causing the error. Remove the same and all will be well.